# Uploading to SharePoint 2013 slow from explorer

Tags: 2013, performance, explorer

When uploading from Windows Explorer (Windows 7) to SharePoint 2013, using drag and drop, I get a spinning circle, and the process never seems to complete.

I have turned off 'Automatically detect settings' in IE, to no avail.

I am using IE 9 (company wide standard that can not be changed at this time)

Comment: After reading the question again (missed critical info myself the first time), I think it's important to note that by drag&drop, you mean to say, drag your files and drop them into IE, not the "Explorer View" of a library, correct ? If this is what is failing, it may have to do with the plugin used in IE for this functionality or an internal SP function failing, have you checked the ULS logs?

Comment: I am not 100% sure, but this would also mean that WEBDAV does not enter the picture (as it IS used for the Explorer view of the library & where "automatically detect proxy settings" does have an impact"), correct ?

Comment: If my assumption is correct, this post may help you: http://community.office365.com/en-us/forums/154/t/196680.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Anecdotally I have experienced this too and I believe it to be an issue with WebDAV. Each file you want to copy over via explorer issues about 5-7 http requests as witnessed via Fiddler. In our case people were trying to copy over thousands of very small files, all 5k or less, and because of all the http traffic going back and forth, it slowed the transfer to a crawl.

Comment: Experienced the same under a limited period after a big go-live under which all users and departments manually move tons of files and documents in

Answer (score -2):

Use PowerShell for uploading/Importing

Comment: Please provide more details. How does your solution will help the user's requirement of drag and drop functionality.?

Comment: I used powershell for uploading /Importing and Exporting documents from sharepoint. I find it quicker way of doing it.if you need Powershell script for that, I can help you

Comment: We have users who go to sites, take photos, then upload the,m with separate documents.  I dont htink i want to have to teach users how to use powershell.  There are 20+ users doing htis.